# Returning mutable reference when self is mutable, otherwise reference

Tags: rust, traits, mutability

I have the following snippet of Rust:

```
pub fn scope(&mut self) -> &mut HashMap<String, Type> {
    let idx = self.vars.len() - 1;
    &mut self.vars[idx]
}
```

I've realized that I have some contexts where I would like to use this function with a non-mutable version of the function e.g.:

```
pub fn scope(&self) -> &HashMap<String, Type> {
    let idx = self.vars.len() - 1;
    &self.vars[idx]
}
```

There's only 3 `mut`s removed between the two functions. Can I somehow turn these into one function that derives the mutability of my returned reference depending on the mutability of `self`? Is there perhaps some kind of trait I can make use of or similar?

Comment: On a side note, `self.vars.iter_mut().rev().next().unwrap()` is a one-liner for what you're doing there, which does no indexing. :)

Comment: Coolio, didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have a single function to achieve that. However, it is actually conventional (and recommended by the [API guidelines](https://github.com/brson/rust-api-guidelines#ownership-suffixes-use-_mut-_ref-c-own-suffix)) to have `_mut` variants of the same function for that purpose:

```
pub fn scope(&self) -> &HashMap<String, Type> {
    let idx = self.vars.len() - 1;
    &self.vars[idx]
}

pub fn scope_mut(&mut self) -> &mut HashMap<String, Type> {
    let idx = self.vars.len() - 1;
    &mut self.vars[idx]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a heap, I'll go with that then!